# Spring boot program caching old files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I have created a Spring Boot Maven project where a set of files are updated(just the content, not the name) during execution. The new files are not displayed on the html page but instead the old ones. When I rebuild the project and execute again the new files appear. Browser cache is off. How can I fix this issue without having to rebuild every time?

Comment: I assume those are files included in your "resources" directory? When you build a spring project those files are copied to maven's "target" folder from which the program runs (or the JAR when you package your project). You need to rebuild your project for those files to be copied over again. If you're using IntelliJ, you can use Ctrl+B to quickly rebuild your project.

Comment: I see that now. Is there a way to show updating content?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this issue without having to rebuild every time?

You can use [spring-boot-devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html).

use ref to configure-

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools

OR

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-developer-tools-and-live-reload